# Updating an atom / scope

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I'm trying to change the value of an atom which holds information about the state of a game.

The code is as follows:

```
(def initial-state {:pos [0 0] :dir go-right})
(defonce app-state (atom initial-state))

(defn go-right [[x y]] [(inc x) y])

(defn new-pos [state]  ((:dir @state) (:pos @state))))

(defn update-state [app-state] 
  (assoc @app-state :pos (new-pos app-state)))
```

I have a function that should update the `:pos` of the atom, based on the function stored in "`:dir`".

My problem is that in the `new-pos` function, I get an error saying that basically, @state is `nil`.

Error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of null`

What a I missing?

Comment: We need more code.  What's the `swap!` call look like?  What's the source for `go-right`?  What's the error?

Comment: It breaks before the swap, on the new-pos function.

Comment: Is it possible that the value of `:dir` is `nil`?  Could `go-right` be nil at the point that it's put into the map? I know Clojure but not the ways in which Clojurescript differs.  I don't know if what I'm suggesting is at all plausible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are defining your atom before you have declared the `go-right` function. When you dereference it, you'll get `nil`.

```
(def app-state (atom { :dir go-right :pos [0 0] }))
(:dir @state) ;; ===> nil
```

You could re-arrange your code, but I think a better solution would be to use a simpler data type, such as a semantically appropriate keyword.

```
(def app-state (atom { :dir :right :pos [0 0] }))
```

Then use it to reference the appropriate function once the atom is dereferenced.

```
(def movement { :right go-right
                :left  go-left
                :up    go-up
                :down  go-down })

(defn new-pos [state]
  (let [dir  (:dir state)
        pos  (:pos state)
        move (get movement dir)]
    (move pos)))
```

This way you'll be able to serialize your `app-state` atom, which will allow you to save the state to disk and load it again later.

I'd also opt for using a generic movement function, rather than hardcoding for each direction.

```
(defn move [[dx dy] [x y]]
  [(+ dx x) (+ dy y)])

(def movement { :left  (partial move [-1 0])
                :right (partial move [1 0])
                :up    (partial move [0 1])
                :down  (partial move [0 -1]) })
```

You probably don't want start calling `assoc` on the manually deferenced atom either. This will result in a need to use `reset` and you can avoid all of that by using `swap` in the first place.

We can remove all of the deref calls and let `swap` handle them instead. Functions are generally more useful if they just work with plain data. Let the lower level dereferencing happen elsewhere.

```
(defn update-state [app-state] 
  (assoc app-state :pos (new-pos app-state)))
```

Finally, to update the state atom, use swap.

```
(swap! app-state update-state)
;; ===> {:dir :right, :pos [1 0]}
```

---

**Complete Code - Works at [Clojurescript.net](http://clojurescript.net/)'s REPL**

```
(defn move [[dx dy] [x y]]
  [(+ dx x) (+ dy y)])

(def movement { :left  (partial move [-1 0])
                :right (partial move [1 0])
                :up    (partial move [0 1])
                :down  (partial move [0 -1]) })

(defn new-pos [state]
  (let [dir  (:dir state)
        pos  (:pos state)
        move (get movement dir)]
    (move pos)))

(defn update-state [app-state] 
  (assoc app-state :pos (new-pos app-state)))

(def app-state (atom { :dir go-right :pos [0 0] }))

(swap! app-state update-state)
```

Comment: I concur with this, but also note that (instead of rearranging the code) you also have the option of forward declaring `go-right`, using [declare](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/declare).